# Why does my Enum parameter goes back to default value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

---

I have created 4 levels, but I'm stuck in the first two because my enum Level keeps going back to default=level_1.
So I'm stuck between levels 1 and 2. Why does my parameters go back to initial/default value?

This is true as well for any other parameters (int) I've tried.

I have already refreshed the scenes in the build setting.

//the enum parameter I use

```
enum Level { Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4 };

Level currentLevel = Level.Level_1;
```

//the loading next scene function

```
private void LaodNextScene()
{
    switch (currentLevel)
    {
        case Level.Level_1:
            {
                print("loading level 2");
                currentLevel = Level.Level_2;
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Level_2");
                break;
            }
        case Level.Level_2:
            {
                print("loading level 3");
                currentLevel = Level.Level_3;
                SceneManager.LoadScene("level_3");
                break;
            }
        case Level.Level_3:
            {
                print("loading level 4");
                currentLevel = Level.Level_4;
                SceneManager.LoadScene("level_4");
                break;
            }
        case Level.Level_4:
            {
                print("loading level 4 again");
                SceneManager.LoadScene("level_4");
                break;
            }
        default:
            print("invalid level");
            break;
    }
}
```

//the loading first scene function

```
private void LaodFirstScene()
{
    currentLevel = Level.Level_1;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(currentLevel.ToString());
}
```

I expect to be able to move forward in my levels, but I'm stuck in the first two:

When I die - level 1 restarts.

When I win - level 1 goes to level 2, however level 2 restarts itself.

Comment: Could you please show the code of `SceneManager.LoadScene`?

Comment: I suspect that when you are loading any scene your `currentLevel` resets to Level.Level_1... Inside `LoadNextScene()` try add `currentLevel = (Level)SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;`

Comment: @khlr you mean the function of the the class ? it is a unity spaceName

Comment: @Ruan indeed it is.

Comment: Show the code where you call `LaodNextScene()`

Comment: I think there could be a case-sensitivity issue: The first argument to `SceneManager.LoadScene` is uppercase: `Level_2`. The others are lowercase (`level_3` and so on...). This may be a problem.

Comment: @khlr first of all thanks for noticing  , but unfortunately it did not help =/

Comment: @Ruan IT WORKED!! can you pls explain your solution?

Comment: @Lior_WebDev check out my answer, you can replace `currentLevel = Level.Level_1;` with `currentLevel = (Level)SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;` or follow the other solution.

Comment: Consider transforming currentLevel in a get/set property with a backikng field, and put a break point within set to catch the point where code change that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the switch statement you set `currentLevel` to the next level, then you load a new scene. I suspect that when the new scene loads `currentLevel = Level.Level_1` is called again and resets `currentLevel`

You can try and replace that line to something like `currentLevel = (Level)SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;`

or you can make a Game Manager that keeps track of the current level with the singleton approach. It's a bit more complicated but probably a more elegant solution.

If you want to know more about singletons:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPKAgyp8cno
- https://www.studica.com/blog/how-to-create-a-singleton-in-unity-3d
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116009/in-unity-how-do-i-correctly-implement-the-singleton-pattern